# How can I create a link to a deployed website in my TeamCity build server?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

My staging build configuration runs through all the build steps and finally deploys the application at, say `http://build90.qa.testsite.com/`, which has been very useful for showing to stakeholders.

Right now I have a script that e-mails users the link to the deployed site, which is nice but it would be better to have a link somewhere in the TeamCity user interface so that people can go to the newly deployed website. There seems to be no built-in way to do this. If the "description" field supported parameters, I could do it there for the latest build, but nothing historic.

Honestly, the best solution I can think of right now is some sort of browser extension, but that doesn't help on mobile devices.

Comment: Is your deployed website link diff for each build?

Comment: Yes, it is. The syntax is `http://build$number$.qa.testsite.com/` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to set up a server, on, say, `http://latest.qa.example.com/`, and have TeamCity set that server to redirect to the latest `http://buildNN.qa.example.com/` . That way, users don't even have to go to TeamCity to get to the latest site.

Of course, that doesn't make it easy to go to historical runs.

Comment: I really like the latest.qa.example.com idea; I think I'll implement it. I don't think TeamCity really has anything built in to solve this particular problem so I'll leave it here until the TC crew sort this out.